# Detailed estimate of the magnitude for the constant appearing in maximal regularity of the inhomogeneous heat equation

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, parabolic-pde, regularity

For any $T \in (0,\infty)$ and the $\mathbb{T}^3=(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})^3$ together with $1< p,q < \infty$, let us consider the following Cauchy problem:
\begin{equation}
\partial_t U - \alpha \Delta U= f(x,t) \text{ for } t>0 \text{ and } U(x,0)=0
\end{equation}
where $f(x,t) \in L^q\bigl([0,T], L^p(\mathbb{T}^3) \bigr)$ and $\alpha \in (0,\infty)$ is some fixed constant.

Then, it is well-known that there exists a unique solution $U(x,t)$ of this Cauchy problem with maximal regularity in the sense that
\begin{equation}
\lVert \partial_t U \rVert_{L^{q}_t L^p_x}+\alpha \lVert \Delta U \rVert_{L^{q}_t L^p_x} \leq C\lVert f \rVert_{L^{q}_t L^p_x}
\end{equation}
with $C>0$ being independent of $f$

My question now is that, how does this $C$ depend on $(T,\alpha,p,q)$?

In particular, if $1< p,q <2$, is it possible to set $C=1$?

This kind of fine details does not seem to turn up anywhere I have looked for. Could anyone please help me? I guess that $C$ may NOT depend on $\alpha$ via scaling of the torus $\mathbb{T}^3$, but not sure...

Comment: Well, the estimate fails for $p = 1$, so the constant blows up as $p \rightarrow 1$. It blows up, if I recall correctly, like $1/(p - 1)$; you can check this in e.g. Stein's harmonic analysis book. While your setting is superficially different, this is basically a version of the Calderon-Zygmund theorem.